# Windows service stopped after log off

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a test windows service using C# visual studio. It simply inserts current date-time to  database table. The service runs every 30 minutes. But when the system logged off the service stops.Service runs when i logged again. Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a tidy stop?  i.e is OnStop called? If not there is likely an exception causing it to terminate, examine the event log.  What do you mean by "runs every 30 mins"?  If there is some type of scheduling, what is it?

Comment: I have added a timer in windows service with an interval of 30 mins.If it runs  at 10 AM  , next insertion of data will be on 10.30 AM and so on. There is no problem in inserting data using the service. if the system is logged off (like more than an hour) then no insertion of data. When I logged in again in the insertion of data continues with an interval of 30 minutes. When i stop the service service stop time will inserted into the table

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  I'm having the same.

Comment: Me too... Windows freeze after 2 AM